# Rational functions that are positive on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

I am studying chapter 14 in Rudin "real and complex analysis" and I am trying to solve number 4  page 293, in which he asks to find the form of rational functions that are positive on the unit circle.

I started from the fact that these functions have same number of zeros as poles,as he mentions,  but i couldn't elaborate. Rudin mentions considering functions of the form

$$f_{a,b}(z) = \frac{(z-a)(1-\bar a z)}{(z-b)(1-\bar b z)},$$

where $|a|,|b|<1.$

Then I tried to approach this problem to the form of rational functions which map unit circles to unit circles , and thought that maybe be they will have almost the same form with some rotation or something ,but i couldn't  solve it .
So any help is appreciated .

Comment: But you are leaving out the most important part of the hint: Rudin suggests considering terms of a certain form. Please state the problem - and its hint - completely. (Also note these are not conformal mappings, so you need to edit the title.)

Comment: i can't write latex  yet that's why i didn't write it , but i tried examples of that form , it doesn't give me something on the real line ,so i don't know how to use it .

Comment: thanks for the advise :) i thought that it might have something to do with conformal mappings that's why i mentioned it .

Comment: 1. It's time you learned LaTex. Really, it's not that hard to ge the basics down. 2. Please mention the functions Rudin mentions as a hint! I don't get why you leave this out! (Yes, I know you don't know what to do with them, but someone else may know.)

Comment: i told u i don't know how to write them, i will go search for how to write them and come back with them , hopefully.

Comment: OK, I didn't know you were specifically talking about those functions. I'll help you out

Comment: i would appreciate it .

Comment: @zhw thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: First show each $f_{a,b}$ is positive on the unit circle. (And the hint for that is to multiply top and bottom by $\bar z.$)

---

Added later: Let $\mathbb {D}$ be the open unit disc. Let $r(z)$ be a rational function with no poles on $\partial D$ such that $r>0$ on $\partial D.$ Then as mentioned, the number of poles of $r$ in $\mathbb {D}$ equals the number of zeros of $r$ in $\mathbb {D},$ counted by muliplicity. Let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be the poles, $b_1, \dots, b_n$ be the zeros. Then

$$g(z) = r(z)\prod_{k=1}^n f_{a_k,b_k}(z)$$

defines a holomorphic function on some $D(0,R),R>1.$ Since each $f_{a_k,b_k}$ is positive on $\partial D,$ and $r$ is assumed to have the same property, $g$ is positive on $\partial D.$ That implies $g \equiv c$ on $D(0,R),$ where $c$ is a positive constant. It follows that

$$r(z) = c\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{f_{a_k,b_k}(z)} , z \in D(0,R)\setminus \{a_1,\dots ,a_n\}.$$

Now a simple argument using the identity principle shows that the above holds on all of $\mathbb {C}$ minus the set of poles of this product, i.e., it holds on $\mathbb {C}\setminus \{a_1,\dots , a_n, 1/\overline {a_1},\dots ,1/\overline {a_n}\}.$

Comment: ok so i got a "real" answer that i need to show positive, but i think i can do it (i will confirm that later) , so if this function is positive on the unit circle, how can i show that every rational function that is positive on the unit circle is of the form of product of  f_{a,b} ?

Comment: @Butterfly If a rational function is real-valued on the unit circle, what does that imply about the zeros and the poles of the function?

Comment: @DanielFischer This was noted in the question.

Comment: @zhw. Not quite. I'm trying to draw attention to another aspect, that, together with the fact mentioned in the question, should answer the question in Butterfly's comment.

Comment: maybe i should use the fact that R(z) =R(1/(z\bar)

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm ... I would just cancel poles and zeros with a product of these special functions, leaving a holo. fn. on a nbhd of the closed disc that is positive on the circle.

Comment: @Butterfly You need one more conjugation, $R(1/\overline{z}) = \overline{R(z)}$. Or $R(z) = \overline{R(1/\overline{z})}$. Yes, use that. What does that tell you about zeros and poles?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, but first you need to know that you actually can cancel poles and zeros with a product of such factors.

Comment: we can cancel them because each zero , it's conjugate is a pole ? and z and 1\(z/bar) are equal on the unit disk

Comment: @DanielFischer But #poles = #zeros.

Comment: @zhw. That's the one half. The other is that the zeros (and the poles) lie symmetric to the unit circle.

Comment: " I would just cancel poles and zeros with a product of these special functions, leaving a holo. fn. on a nbhd of the closed disc that is positive on the circle." How can u do it? @zhw

Comment: I added further details.

Comment: Thank u so much for ur time and help